# Optimal rotation in 3d with Kabsch algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, math

### The Problem

I am trying to use the [Kabsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm) to find the optimal rotation between two sets of 4 points, but the errors I am getting are unacceptably large. I want to map the red points (***P***) into the blue points (***Q***), shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZeor.png).

### What I've tried

Here is my implementation of the Kabsch algorithm, given numpy arrays of the `mapping_points` (***P***) and `true_points` (***Q***)

```
mapped_centroid = np.average(mapping_points, axis=0)
true_centroid = np.average(true_points, axis=0)

mapping_points -= mapped_centroid
true_points -= true_centroid

h = np.matmul(mapping_points.T, true_points)
u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(h)

d = np.linalg.det(v @ u.T)
e = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, d]])

r = v @ e @ u.T
tt = true_centroid - np.matmul(r, mapped_centroid)
```

I then apply the mapping to the centroid-adjusted points in ***P***:

```
map_list = []
for i in mapping_points:
    point = np.matmul(r, i) + tt
    map_list.append(np.reshape(point, (1, 3)))
mapped_xyz = np.vstack(map_list)
```

However, plotting the `mapped_xyz` and `true_points` gives very inaccurate results shown in the above plot. Any ideas on what I've done wrong?

### Additional information

I am actually trying to map between 2 networks of several hundred nodes. One network is the "true positions", the other is a "relative map" of the network. I am using the anchors nodes ***Q*** and the corresponding points ***P*** to find the best transformation, and then map the rest of the nodes.

I have noticed that there is a strong sensitivity to the choice of anchor nodes (which I am sampling at random). With only 3 anchor nodes, the mapping is occasionally close, sometimes off by a single rotation, sometimes mirrored about the z-axis. I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

## Edit

Here is the data for the points ***Q*** and ***P*** used in the above plot.

```
Q = [[ 1774.11606309 -4241.11341178  5259.04277742]
     [ 6079.70499031   -98.14197972 -3442.0914569 ]
     [  813.07069876  3334.26289147 -6112.55652513]
     [ 1856.72080823  2328.86927901  6322.16611888]]
P = [[ 3172.79468418   727.52462347  7122.70450243]
     [  165.28953155 -3552.32467068 -2045.15346584]
     [ 5292.45250241 -1748.52037006 -6181.40300009]
     [ 1893.07584225  5897.19719625  3130.41287776]]
```

Comment: Could you post your data for P and Q?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Added data into the post. Thank you for looking at my problem!

Comment: How sure are you that the sets are similar, related by a geometric transformation? With your data the `d` is actually negative, which should only happen if the points are almost co-planar, making the last singular value decidedly smaller than the other two. However with the data the singular values are  [1.25294888e+08 2.93046686e+07 1.18440213e+07], of similar magnitude.

Comment: Btw., your code is correct, but why do you use all 3 different calls for the matrix multiplication? If you expect `@` to work once, you could also use it everywhere.

Comment: @LutzLehmann the sets are definitely not perfectly similar, but I hoped they would be close enough to map with "mild" accuracy. The mapped set's relative positions were determined with [multi-dimensional scaling](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.MDS.html). I suppose the error is from the MDS mapping. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured it out (kicking myself for it). numpy's linalg.svd returns the *transpose* of v (technically conjugate transpose), so my kabsch implementation was incorrect. This explains why it was getting wildly different results depending on the anchor node selection. It should be:

```
h = mapping_points.T @ true_points
u, s, vt = np.linalg.svd(h)
v = vt.T

d = np.linalg.det(v @ u.T)
e = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, d]])

r = v @ e @ u.T
```

Comment: Great job.  I found myself in the same conundrum and this simple change (v = vt.T) fixed everything.  Kudos!

Comment: Can one say what is the typical value of d in e array?

Comment: This solution is also good. https://zpl.fi/aligning-point-patterns-with-kabsch-umeyama-algorithm/

Comment: Anyone encountered a reflection issue where the rotated set is reflected about an arbitrary axis?